# CP odd Higgs coupling to bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory

It is stated that CP-odd Higgs does no couple to vector bosons at tree level. Terms like $A V_\mu V^\mu$ (where V is W or Z) can only appear through loop diagrams (and if they appear at tree-level, they are not renormalizable). Can anyone explain in basic principles why these terms are not allowed at tree level, and how do you lead to non-renormalizability?

Comment: ...have you tried to draw a tree-level diagram generating that term?